# Markov chain to solve a particle fusion problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A sequence of elementary particles arrive at Poisson rate $r$ to a system. A pair of elementary particles can be fused into a level-$1$ particle. The fusion process succeeds with probability $p_0$. With probability $1-p_0$ the fusion fails and the two particles are distroyed. The above fusion process is then extended such that a pair of level-$i$ particles can be fused into a level-$(i+1)$ particle. The fusion process succeeds with probability $p_i$. We seek the rate of producing level-$k$ particles. I would like to know the process of solving this problem using Markov chain.

Comment: Looks very interesting. A possible state space may be $S = \prod_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{N}_0$ with $s = (s_0,s_1,\ldots)$ and $s_i$ the actual number of level-$i$-particles. But what is missing is generally the time rate at which particles fuse. Please be more explicite.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thank you. I am not sure to understand your question. As long as we have 2 level-i particles, we execute the fusion process. Assume the process takes zero time to execute, and the process succeeds with prob. p_i.

Answer (score 1):

If I undrstand your intention correctly a possible Markov chain in continuous time is given by the following data:
$S = \left\{s \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}_0} \colon \sum_{i=0}^\infty s_i < \infty \right\}$. Let $s = (s_0,s_1,\ldots)$ to $t = (t_0,t_1,\ldots)$ be two states in $S$ and assume that $s_0,\ldots,s_k = 1$ and $s_{k+1} = 0$. Then for a transition from $s$ to $t$ with positive rate we must have $s_{k+2} = t_{k+2}, s_{k+3} = t_{k+3}, \ldots$ . And the rate for the transition $s = (1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots)$ to $t = (0,\ldots,0,1,\ldots)$ will be $r \cdot \prod_{i=0}^k p_i$ and to $t = (0,\ldots,0,0,\ldots)$ will be $r \cdot (1-\prod_{i=0}^k p_i)$ (all particles at level $0,\ldots,k$ are destroyed.

Comment: For chemical reactions this model doesn't seem to make much sense. Is it an engenering problem?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is an engineering problem that I abstracted in a more understandabe way